# Can I get the same results from one query after normalizing tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have just broken apart a table called submissions that used to hold a column for each question a user had until I realized this table could grow into infinity if users kept coming up with new questions. I've normalized the tables but now I'm struggling to get the same results as before. Since it is many to many I now have:

```
CREATE TABLE Submissions ( 
submission_id INT(11) NOT NULL, 
);

CREATE TABLE Questions ( 
question_id INT(11) NOT NULL, 
);

CREATE TABLE Submission_questions ( 
question_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
submission_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
submit_quest_id INT(11) NOT NULL, 
);
```

It used to be possible to pull all the questions I needed by running one single query of SELECT * from Submissions and then listing the columns I wanted. My question is, is it possible to still run one single query and still get the answers to the questions I need? I have the submission_id and the question_id so I'm assuming its possible but I've looked around and didn't see a query that addresses this and the more I read the more wrapped around the axle I become.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing about questions in your old query and there are no fields you were joining on in your new table definition. Are you sure your both `submissions` tables are from the same project? Or were the join fields your "questions"? Your group by seems also to be wrong, your old query probably ended at the manufacturers.man_name part of group by.

Answer (score 0):

> It used to be possible to pull all the questions I needed by running
>   one single query of SELECT * from Submissions and then listing the
>   columns I wanted.

What was in those columns? A separate question in each column?

> My old query was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM manufacturers 
JOIN submissions on manufacturers.manufacturer_id=submissions.manufacturer_id 
JOIN products on products.product_id=submissions.product_id 
JOIN product_group on submissions.category=product_group.id 
WHERE submissions.approval_status='2' 
GROUP BY product_group.group,manufacturers.man_name", 
         "submission_id", 
         "date, man_name, group, feedback"
```

Well, that doesn't look anything like `SELECT * FROM Submissions` to me. It doesn't really look like it'll run at all.

Edit your question, paste in (don't type in) your DDL statements. (Your CREATE TABLE statements.) Include some sample data as SQL INSERT statements. Make sure it's clear what you were selecting in that old "SELECT * FROM Submissions" query. Then we can have another go at it.

Comment: Thanks catcall, Ive edited the questions as asked. My old submissions table had 20 columns(and growing) of questions. Now all of those columns have been transferred to the table questions as seen above where I can just add questions as users have them. The problem is I can't query the same as before and my question is how do I create a single query to get to the answers of the questions. Now I obviously need to pull those from the submissions_questions table rather than just the submissions table. Just not sure how

Comment: @DevNewb: Your tables seem to store no questions and no answers, only ID numbers.   Did you cut all the information that might be useful to us before saving your edit?  That's probably not going to help you get better answers. Maybe including your old, 20-column structure with a handful of SQL INSERT statements would also help.